# MySQL left join count not showing all entries from left table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two **tables**: `vcases(id,statusCategoryID,userID)` and `vstatuses(id,category)`.

I'm trying to display a dashboard where user can see number of cases they **submitted** under each **category**.

I tried **left join** but I'm not getting all the category names for a **particular** user.

This is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT vs.name as `catName`
      , COUNT(vs.name) as `count` 
  FROM vstatuses vs 
  LEFT 
  JOIN vcases v 
    ON vs.id = v.statusCategoryID 
 WHERE v.userID = 2 
 GROUP 
    BY vs.names 
 ORDER
    BY vs.id
```

I want to display like this

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Category | Submitted | Opened | Solved |
| Count    |    3      |   1    |   0    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

But I'm getting this

```
+-------------------------------+
| Category | Submitted | Opened |
| Count    |    3      |   1    |
+-------------------------------+
```

I want to include the `categoryName` even if there is no case under that **category**.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter should be with the `ON` clause

```
 LEFT JOIN vcases v ON vs.id=v.statusCategory AND v.userID = 2
```

Otherwise it's as if it's an `INNER JOIN`